# Variable name: num_threads or nr_threads?

Tags: coding-style

It's a question about coding styles. When you define a variable for storing the information of the number of threads (or the number of anything), do you name it "num_threads" or "nr_threads"? Or are there even better names?

Thank you!
Cui

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer to name that variable "numberOfThreads".